# Communicating between two computers with c#

Tags: c#, c, sockets

So, I am trying to build some kind of remote control application with C# but I don't know anything about Socket Programming. I did a lot of search on it but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

The only thing I need is to communicate between two computers over the internet and I just need a way to be able to send and receive a simple String variable like "robot:move" but I can't figure out how and I'd be more than happy if someone could help me.

P.S. I haven't started the project yet so it doesn't matter if it's windows form or console application

Thanks in Advance

Update :

Thanks for the help I learned how to use WCF and I managed to create my desired application but unfortunately it only works locally and I don't have static IP address or Windows/IIS hosting to host it over the internet. The only thing I have is a Linux/Apache host and I tried mono, it was a no go. So I wanted to know if there are  any different solutions to my problem.

P.S. Is there another programming language like C or JAVA that makes this possible?
If so can you give me a link about how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to do it using a simple console application?

Comment: This is a little overly broad of a question for this site and may be closed unless you add more details about your restraints and requirements [by editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20457715/edit). I would recommend not dealing with `sockets` directly and instead go with a library that hides all that stuff for you to make it simpler to use, like [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However once you choose a technology feel free asking a new *specific* question about it if you become lost or don't understand an aspect of it.

Comment: yes a console application would be fine

Comment: Well I'm a web developer and I have never done such things before so I'm not familiar with the technologies for this matter but I'll definitely dig into WCF, Thanks for you r answer

Comment: The generic term for "Two programs talking to each other" (be it over the internet or between to programs on the same computer) is called Intra Process communication, or IPC. [Here is a good MSDN page explaining about various IPC methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the pros and cons for each. Hopefully that will help you narrow down your search. (WCF actually acts as a wrapper for various forms of IPC, so you could do WCF over Sockets or WCF or named pipes, or WCF over MailSlots with very little change to your code.)

Comment: IPC is for the same machine not for 2 different computers

Comment: @Ikaso no it is not, look at the first two bullet points on the page I linked under how to decide which IPC method to use: "*- Should the application be able to communicate with other applications running on other computers on a network, or is it sufficient for the application to communicate only with applications on the local computer?*" and "*- Should the application be able to communicate with applications running on other computers that may be running under different operating systems (such as 16-bit Windows or UNIX)?*"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Of course. I thought you were talking about IPC channel on .Net Remoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE: 5 years later**

I would use gRPC with protbuf serialisation now. This would allow you to use different languages for the client and server. ProtoBuf is also full-compatible (supports both backwards and forward compatibility). 
Here is the _"Getting started") documentation: https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html

---

I think the best solution for you is using WCF service.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691(v=vs.110).aspx
Here is a short example from the above link:

```
// Define a service contract.
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(double n1, double n2);
    // Other methods are not shown here.
}
```

and the client

```
// Create a client object with the given client endpoint configuration.
CalculatorClient calcClient = new CalculatorClient("CalculatorEndpoint"));
// Call the Add service operation.
double value1 = 100.00D;
double value2 = 15.99D;
double result = calcClient.Add(value1, value2);
Console.WriteLine("Add({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);
```

The whole point is that you have a contract (interface) and a service (class) which implements this interface. Then when this service is hosted in web, forms or console app you can add a reference to the service from another app it doesn't matter what - there are variety of transports (bindings) available.
Here is a link to getting started section on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731067(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, I'm gonna try WCF.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there are various ways for communicating between components:

1. Sockets
2. Using .NET Remoting [obsolete]
3. Using WCF
4. Using WebClient

Which one of them to use depend on the purpose of the project. I suggest to read on each and decide which is applicable for your problem.

Comment: .NET Remoting is almost identicial to WCF in its use, but Remoting is deprecated and is not recommended for new software projects.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - WCF is for SOA. Not all applications need SOA. Now, it is true that .Net Remoting is an older technology but I don't think it is deprecated. Did you see such statement from Microsoft?

Comment: Right on the top of the [MSDN page for .Net Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72x4h507%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in bold: "***This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the  Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).***"

Answer (score 0):

Well if the computers are on the same network i would be using `TCPListener` and `TCPClient` along with `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`classes to establish communication. They require IP Address and Ports for communication.

They can also work for communicate over the internet provided you can solve the firewall issues.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is not a good idea, working directly with TCP (sockets), especially if your new to doing it, is **very** hard to get right on your first try. For situations like the OP is describing there are a lot of better solutions available (both in .NET itself and free 3rd party librires) that are a lot easier to use and require less code to set up.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at SignalR

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: Does SignalR require ASP.net? It is not exactly clear that is what the OP is using.

Comment: SignalR is really not applicable in this scenario.

Comment: SignalR doesn't provide a nice/practical way of getting a direct response from a request. For example say i made a request from a web api service controller class to a .net client i've got no nice way of getting the response of that request back in that controller class.